# Indexed columns in SQL Server do not appear to work for basic queries according to execution plan

Tags: sql-server, index

Disclaimer: I'm not a DBA. I have picked up a few things from this board in the past that I'm building from.

I have a table of google analytics session start times. I have an index on each column. I want to filter for all sessions that were started between two dates. Screenshot below shows the query, and the index.

[image: Query text and index properties]

The query runs quickly but I do not believe it's using the index based on the Execution plan which both says that there's a missing index and shows a table scan rather than an index scan:

[image: execution]

Why?

Is it because of something about the way I'm searching through the datetime? If instead of looking between dates, I set it equal to a date, the execution plan shows it using the index:

[image: Using index]

But it's not just this table or datetime. Here's a different table with an index on a varchar column:

[image: metadata index]

And a simple query on this one also tells me I'm missing the index:

[image: missing md index]

I'm stumped.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want SQL Server to use that index for that specific query, you need to include the `session_id` column.  Otherwise, for each row it finds it will have to go do a key lookup into the base table.  It will choose to do this for small result sets, but once you get above a certain number of rows (["the tipping point"](https://sqlperformance.com/2020/05/t-sql-queries/visualizing-the-tipping-point-with-plan-explorer)), SQL Server thinks it's more efficient to just scan the whole base table.

You can use the `INCLUDE` clause of the `CREATE INDEX` syntax to accomplish this:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Start_Time
ON GoogleAnalytics.SessionStartTimes (session_start_time)
INCLUDE (session_id);
```

Answer (score 7):

**Let's break down what's going on, step-by-step:**

- The compiler needs to get the value of `session_id` for each row. `session_id` is not in the index, so it needs to be looked up from the base table
- Your table has no clustered index, it is a heap table, and every row is located using its RID. A clustered index would need a key lookup instead
- So the compiler needs to decide whether to look up the index and then lookup the base table, or whether to just scan the base table from start to finish. It decides whether to do this based on estimated rowcounts from the statistics histogram.
- Your first query has more estimated rows than the second, for obvious reasons. Sp the compiler has decided that the cost of extra lookups are not worth it.

**You have a number of solutions:**

- Put `session_id` in the index. This does not have to be part of the key, it can be an `INCLUDE` column. I do not advise this as it leaves the table as a heap.
- Change the index to be **clustered** on `session_start_time`. This means all columns are included in the index. Remember, a clustered index is not extra to the table, it *is* the table. It is generally more efficient than a heap table anyway. Note that the PK does *not* need to be the clustering key.
- Create a clustered index on `session_id`. Then your non-clustered index will automatically include `session_id` (because that is the row locator). You may want to make this a PK, which I suspect should be the case anyway. Again, it doesn't *have* to be the PK.

**Which option you choose will depend on what column is normally filtered or grouped.** If this query was the only one done on the table then you would cluster on `session_start_time`.

Comment: session_id should be unique in that table. I'm nervous to make it formally a PK because a) my ignorance and b) the process I have for updating this table isn't super clean and I'd be worried about having a PK causing problems. Maybe I shouldn't be.
This table will probably almost always be queried like this. I'd be doing ad hoc analysis for a certain period of time and I'd come here to grab all sessions for that period, and then go grab the data on those sessions from other tables.

Comment: OK so make a non-unique clustered index. Clustering does not by itself imply unique (although it is often the case)

Comment: Thank you for these suggestions. I tried the solution above first because it was a bit simpler for me and for the simple queries it worked well. I may re-visit what you've said as I start joining these tables together.

Comment: @Charlieface +1, this is a quality answer with a ton of very good information. The only minor thing I'd say is your first solution **is** a good one **in addition** to the second one. So I wouldn't necessarily advise against it, I'd just make it clear to users that both that fix + adding a **clustered index** to the Table is a good move to make too.

Comment: @J.D. Thank you. I don't think so, they are mutually exclusive (even though it doesn't look it at first sight). 1 and 2 are mutually excl because they duplicate the same index key and include column (I have no info on existence of other columns). 1 and 3 are mutually exclusive because, as I say, clustering implies an include on the NCI anyway, so it's not necessary to actually add it to the NCI.

Comment: @Charlieface Sorry I *slightly* misread your second suggestion (because I missed your first word "*Change*"). Rather, I meant your first suggestion is a good one if a clustered index is also added to the Table (so two indexes in this scenario) because **Heap** tables usually aren't needed (and suck lol) unless being used for temporary data staging in **ETL**. So in short I guess I meant one can implement your first suggestion and fix the **Heap** by implementing an additional clustered index as needed.